# SIGSEGV; missing file; when running program using sscanf

Tags: c++, omnet++

I will below describe the error that I get when calling the function `sscanf`.

Some of my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
(..)
int device_num = 0;
int frameTime = sscanf(currentStringVector[2].c_str(), "%d", &device_num);
```

It is part of a module of OmNet++, so I compile it using OmNet++ .
I get the following error message in GDB:

> "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __rawmemchr_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../rawmemchr.S:31
>   31    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../rawmemchr.S: Filen eller katalogen finns inte.
>       in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../rawmemchr.S"

The problem started to incur when I called `sscanf`.

I am running the program in Ubuntu on a 64-bits system.
How do I resolve the above problem?

Thanks!

Comment: could you print the 'currentStringVector[2].c_str()' out before calling sscanf?

Comment: Can you post the code that declares and populates `currentStringVector`?

Comment: A self containing piece of code (that would run and exhibit the same behaviour on e.g. ideone.com) would be most useful for this problem to debug.

Comment: How big is is the vector `currentStringVector` (i.e. the return value of `size`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OMNeT++, you can use a debugger like gdb when running your program from the command line. The IDE also lets you debug your code.

My guess is that `currentStringVector[2].c_str()` is not valid. Maybe the vector is smaller than that.

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, I noticed after posting that the vector was shorter than that length at one instance in the for-loop where it was in.
It was confusing though with the error status: 'File is missing'...